# Building Linux project (make) in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, makefile

I would like to build a Linux project (built by Makefile) using VisualStudio.

The build results of Linux project are bunch of shared objects (so) files.
And, I would like to create dll after building the same project using VisualStudio.

Is there any recommendation for the simplest possible way?

Comment: The simplest way: read the makefile, understand what it does, configure your VS project to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is no simple tool to just convert the makefile into visual studio to do the same, as these systems have different capabilities.

If the makefile is part of some project, there is a chance, that it was generated by some general tool (like cmake), the cmake source used to generated the linux make can be used to create visual studio project files as well.

If you have just the make file, you are left to (as pointed out in the commend), to understand what it does and configure it manually in visual studio.